# Which one is more correct to say? "Sit" or "Sitting"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

> - The sit of her dress was perfect.
> - The sitting of her dress was perfect.

I didn't know that "sit" could be a noun form of the verb "to sit". I've been using "sitting" so far, but I came across "sit" as a noun form in this sentence. I don't know which one is more suitable to use.

Comment: I can't say many native speakers saying either of these things.

Comment: Could you possibly mean "the *fit* of her dress"?  I never heard "sit" used that way.

Comment: Why close vote? Care to explain? Or be thought of as one that doesn't know the specific usage of *sit* in this sense.

Comment: @KristinaLopez & up-voter ***Noun**: If the facing is not properly anchored, it may adversely affect the sit of the fabric.* (http://www.educationbug.org/a/set-vs-sit.html) http://english.stackexchange.com/a/106954/14666 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/106952/14666 http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sit

Comment: Well, we learn something new every day.  I sew and have not known of this usage before.  (@Kris, thanks for the link, and I did not vote to close).

Answer (score 8):

*Sit* is to the dress as *lay* is to the land.  I believe I heard my grandmother (b. 1881, d. 1981) use this idiom to refer to the fit and arrangement of a dress on the wearer in a seated position.

Answer (score 6):

See the definition of the word sit as a noun [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sit). It *is* an appropriate use of the word, but, as far as I know, it's archaic. Like @DavidSchwartz points out, you won't hear many native speakers using it (save for those in the clothing design industry perhaps).

Comment: [This one](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22readjusting+the+sit+of+his%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is obviously a modern instance (perhaps by a moonlighting fashion designer! :)

Comment: Interesting find!